# Apache destination virtual host certificate when using mod_rewrite or ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, mod-rewrite, proxypass

I am trying to use mod_rewrite or ProxyPass to redirect (PT) the client's request from virtual host A on 443 to different virtual host B on port 4434, also with SSL.
Like that:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off 
ProxyPassMatch    ^/vd https://localhost:4434
```

There is the way I am trying to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:4434%{REQUEST_URI} [PT]
```

The problem is that my client validates server certificate and  the on response the client gets the certificate of the virtual host A on 443 port, instead of virtual host B on 4434 port, so SSL handshake failed.

Is there any way to work around this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: "the client gets the certificate of the virtual host A on 443 port, instead of virtual host B on 4434 port" - yes, that's how a reverse proxy should work. Why (or how?) is the client trying (or needing) to "SSL handshake with server B? Perhaps you do need a "redirect" and not a "proxy"? You say you are "trying to use mod_rewrite" - but there is no "mod_rewrite" here? In what way are you using mod_rewrite? "...to redirect (PT)" - PT?

Comment: I edited the question with mod_rewrite sample

Comment: The `RewriteRule` flag `PT` has little to do with "redirects" or "proxies". The `PT` flag is short for `passthrough`. You perhaps meant to use the `P` (`proxy`) flag which uses mod_proxy to handle the request. However, this probably won't help your current issue. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no

Long answer: the client will authenticate with the certificate of virtual host A, because this is where it's connecting to. Whatever happens on the backend via proxy mode is transparent.
If you want to use virtual host Bs certificate, do a redirect and then the client connects directly to that host, it has to be exposed publicly though.

Comment: Do you mean 302 redirect on client side ? If yes - that is not an option for my case...

Comment: Yes, a 30x redirect is the option you have.